# Functions returning before completion block finished

Tags: swift, jwt, grand-central-dispatch, completionhandler

I'm having trouble using Swifts GCD. I have a function that checks to make sure a token is valid before actually moving on to download the image itself while adding the download task to an array.

The problem is if the token is invalid, after going to fetch a new one, the preloadImage code runs through too quick for the requestPreloadJWTToken completion block to set the downloadTask variable so it isn't nil.

Below is the set up for the download task.

```
static func preloadImage(sku: String)  {
    // If the token exists AND is VALID (not expired) - Get the image.

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    var downloadTask : RetrieveImageDownloadTask? = nil

    if ImageManager.tokenExists() && ImageManager.tokenIsNotExpired(){

        let imageURL = ImageManager.URLBuilder(sku: sku)

        // Create the request and add the token string to the authorization header
        var urlRequest = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string: imageURL)!)
        urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(ImageManager.getTokenString()!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        downloadTask = NetRequest.downloadImage(urlRequest: urlRequest, sku: sku)
    }
    // Else if the token exists AND is INVALID (expired) - Delete the old token, get a new one, and fetch the image
    else if ImageManager.tokenExists() && !ImageManager.tokenIsNotExpired(){
        print("Token expired... Getting new token.")


        _ = ImageManager.deleteToken()
        if let tokenRequest = NetRequest.newTokenRequest(url: "http://\(UrlHelper.buildUrlFrom(SettingsManager.serverURL)){
            group.enter()
            tokenRequest.requestPreloadJWTToken(){
                let imageURL = ImageManager.URLBuilder(sku: sku)

                // Create the request and add the token string to the authorization header
                var urlRequest = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string: imageURL)!)
                urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(ImageManager.getTokenString()!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

                print("Token renewed. Fetching image...")
                downloadTask = NetRequest.downloadImage(urlRequest: urlRequest, sku: sku)
            }
            group.leave()
        }
    }
    // If the token doesn't exist, request a new one and fetch the image.
    else{
        print("Requesting new token...")

        if let tokenRequest = NetRequest.newTokenRequest(url: "http://\(UrlHelper.buildUrlFrom(SettingsManager.serverURL)){
            group.enter()
            tokenRequest.requestPreloadJWTToken() {
                print("Token aquired. Fetching image...")
                let imageURL = ImageManager.URLBuilder(sku: sku)

                // Create the request and add the token string to the authorization header
                var urlRequest = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string: imageURL)!)
                urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(ImageManager.getTokenString()!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

                downloadTask = NetRequest.downloadImage(urlRequest: urlRequest, sku: sku)
            }
            group.leave()
        }
    }
    // This should always happen
    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
       MainController.imageDownloadTasks.append(downloadTask!)
    }
}
```

Below is the token request being created.

```
func requestPreloadJWTToken(completionHandler: @escaping () -> (/*RetrieveImageDownloadTask*/))
{
    // Get the server name, username, and password
    let username = SettingsManager.username
    let password = SettingsManager.password

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Token-Request", qos: .utility, attributes: [.concurrent])

    // Get download directory
    let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

    // Create the header to be used - Add username and password
    self.makeURLRequest()
    self.addPreAuthentication(username, password)

    // Make the request for the token
    Alamofire.download("\(UrlHelper.buildUrlFrom(SettingsManager.serverURL)), method: .post, parameters: nil, headers: self.request.allHTTPHeaderFields, to: destination)
        // Alamofires built in authentication will provide credentials when challenged for authentication
        .authenticate(user: username, password: password)
        .responseString(
            queue: queue,
            completionHandler: { response in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    switch response.result {
                    // If the result was successful, the token string is saved to a file
                    case .success:
                        // Uncomment to see token string value
                        //debugPrint("Value \(response.value!)")
                        completionHandler()
                    case .failure(let error):
                        debugPrint("Failed \(error)")
                    }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

If anyone has some insight into how I can get the completion block from requestPreloadJWT to complete before the preloadImage that would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty. So I figured it out immediately after I made this post... Of course...

Anyway. I simply stuck the group.leave() **inside** the closure in my preloadImage method so it looks like:

```
static func preloadImage(sku: String)  {
    // If the token exists AND is VALID (not expired) - Get the image.

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    var downloadTask : RetrieveImageDownloadTask? = nil

    if ImageManager.tokenExists() && ImageManager.tokenIsNotExpired(){

        let imageURL = ImageManager.URLBuilder(sku: sku)

        // Create the request and add the token string to the authorization header
        var urlRequest = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string: imageURL)!)
        urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(ImageManager.getTokenString()!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        downloadTask = NetRequest.downloadImage(urlRequest: urlRequest, sku: sku)
    }
    // Else if the token exists AND is INVALID (expired) - Delete the old token, get a new one, and fetch the image
    else if ImageManager.tokenExists() && !ImageManager.tokenIsNotExpired(){
        print("Token expired... Getting new token.")


        _ = ImageManager.deleteToken()
        if let tokenRequest = NetRequest.newTokenRequest(url: "http://\(UrlHelper.buildUrlFrom(SettingsManager.serverURL))"){
            group.enter()
            tokenRequest.requestPreloadJWTToken(){
                let imageURL = ImageManager.URLBuilder(sku: sku)

                // Create the request and add the token string to the authorization header
                var urlRequest = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string: imageURL)!)
                urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(ImageManager.getTokenString()!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

                print("Token renewed. Fetching image...")
                downloadTask = NetRequest.downloadImage(urlRequest: urlRequest, sku: sku)
                group.leave()
            }
        }
    }
    // If the token doesn't exist, request a new one and fetch the image.
    else{
        print("Requesting new token...")

        if let tokenRequest = NetRequest.newTokenRequest(url: "http://\(UrlHelper.buildUrlFrom(SettingsManager.serverURL))"){
            group.enter()
            tokenRequest.requestPreloadJWTToken() {
                print("Token aquired. Fetching image...")
                let imageURL = ImageManager.URLBuilder(sku: sku)

                // Create the request and add the token string to the authorization header
                var urlRequest = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string: imageURL)!)
                urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(ImageManager.getTokenString()!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

                downloadTask = NetRequest.downloadImage(urlRequest: urlRequest, sku: sku)
                group.leave()
            }
        }
    }
    // This should always happen
    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
       MainController.imageDownloadTasks.append(downloadTask!)
    }
}
```

I hope this can help whoever comes across it!

Comment: was just working on my answer to this. Might I suggest also refactoring your code since you do almost identical things in each of your completions blocks, so it might be useful to put all of that into a single function.

Comment: Thanks dude. Yeah this part of my code definitely needs a refactor. Still kind of new to the field :p